# What does "bits 6-0" or "bits 10-6 " mean in the javadoc of DataInput?

Tags: java, utf-8

When reading [the javadoc of DataInput specifically in the "Modified UTF-8" section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8). I come across three tables that say "0 bits 6-0" ,"1 1 0 bits 10-6",...,"1 0 bits 5-0".

I'm a Java newbie so to me it looks like subtractions, not sure, but if that's the case and we add it to the ones and zeros it would make 7 bits.
As far as I know, a byte is made up of 8 bits.

What does these "0 bits 6-0..." mean?

Comment: It indicates a range but it looks "reversed" because it is using indexes from most significant digit/bit to less significant one. So if you have single `byte` which represents 8 bits like `10101111` we can assign indexes to it like `[7][6][5][4][3][2][1][0]`. Then range of all digits is `7-0` which will represent bits `10101111`. Range like  6-2 will be `01011` part, etc. In case of `char` which is 16 bits (2 bytes) indexes will be in range 15-0 (range of first byte 15-8; range of second byte 7-0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc is telling you how each byte is divided.

Consider each byte as a vector of 8 individual elements (bits).

The first block has only one byte, and the corresponding possible bit values.

```
byte 1

bit number 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
bit value  0 ? ? ? ? ? ? ? <-- bits 6 - 0
```

This means that for characters encoded in one byte, the leading bit will always be 0. These are the characters from `\u0001` to `\u007F`.

The second block has two bytes and gets a bit more complicated

```
byte 1                       byte 2

bit number 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 | 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
bit value   1  1  0  ?  ?  ? ? ? | 1 0 ? ? ? ? ? ?
                          ^                 ^
                          |                 |
                   bits 10 to 6 of       bits 5 to 0 of
                 the utf-8 codepoint    the utf-8 codepoint
```

These are the characters in the range from `\u0080` to `\u07FF`

So for example, a symbol in this range is µ (micro sign).

In normal unicode the bytes are `11000010 10110101`

Take a look at this character and see how it lines up with the bits for two-byte chars. You have

```
15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8    7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
 1  1  0  0  0  0 1 0    1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1

Bits 10-6 ------*-*-*----*-* ^-^-^-^-^-^----bits 5-0
```

You end up with

```
byte 1                       byte 2

bit number 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 | 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
bit value   1  1  0  -  -  0 1 0 | 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

Where bytes 11 and 12 would be 0 but I put a - in there just to show their (in)significance.

Sorry for the ascii art, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It shows ranges of bits. Bits are numbered, the lowest, least significant bit has index 0, the next bit has index 1, the next bit has index 2 etc. For example, number 13 has binary representation 1101. It means that bit number 0 has value 1, bit number 1 has value 0, and bits number 2 and 3 have value of 1. So, for example, in the documentation "0 bits 6-0" means that the highest bit in the byte must be zero, while seven lower bits with the indexes from 6 to 0 are occupied by your number.

Answer (score 0):

That table is talking about how characters is represented in the modified UTF8 encoding. I'll use this part as an example:

> The null character '\u0000' and characters in the range '\u0080' to '\u07FF' are represented by a pair of bytes.

Notice that you can use 11 bits to represent those numbers. The largest number you can represent with 11 bits is 2^11 - 1 = 2047 = 7FF in hex. Let's number those 11 bits 0 to 10, so bit-10 is the most significant bit, and bit-0 is the least significant.

The table is telling you that in the modified UTF8 encoding, the characters that those numbers are encoded by are instead represented by 2 bytes.

The first byte starts with the bits 110 (these three bits are fixed), followed by bit-10, bit-9, bit-8, bit-7, bit-6 of the number we are trying to represent.

The second byte starts with the bits 10 (these two bits are fixed), followed by bit-5, bit-4, bit-3, bit-2, bit-1, bit-0 of the number.

In short, "bits 10-6" means "bits 10 ***to*** 6", which is not 4, but 5 bits.

I encourage you to compare this with the normal [UTF8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding to see where the difference is.